# Index for character in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have `NSString *string = @"Helo";` and `NSString *editedString = @"Hello";`. How find index for changed character or characters (for example here is `@"l"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a category on NSString that will do what you want.  I've used my StackOverflow username as a postfix on the category method. This is to stop an unlikely potential future collision with a method of the same name. Feel free to change it.

First the interface definition `NSString+Difference.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Difference)

- (NSInteger)indexOfFirstDifferenceWithString_mttrb:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

and the implementation 'NSString+Difference.m`:

```
#import "NSString+Difference.h"

@implementation NSString (Difference)

- (NSInteger)indexOfFirstDifferenceWithString_mttrb:(NSString *)string; {

    // Quickly check the strings aren't identical
    if ([self isEqualToString:string]) 
        return -1;

    // If we access the characterAtIndex off the end of a string
    // we'll generate an NSRangeException so we only want to iterate
    // over the length of the shortest string
    NSUInteger length = MIN([self length], [string length]);

    // Iterate over the characters, starting with the first
    // and return the index of the first occurence that is 
    // different
    for(NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < length; idx++) {
        if ([self characterAtIndex:idx] != [string characterAtIndex:idx]) {
            return idx;
        }
    }

    // We've got here so the beginning of the longer string matches
    // the short string but the longer string will differ at the next
    // character.  We already know the strings aren't identical as we
    // tested for equality above.  Therefore, the difference is at the
    // length of the shorter string.

    return length;        
}

@end
```

You would use the above as follows:

```
NSString *stringOne = @"Helo";
NSString *stringTwo = @"Hello";

NSLog(@"%ld", [stringOne indexOfFirstDifferenceWithString_mttrb:stringTwo]);
```

Comment: not only did you literally rewrite my answer in a different way, but have you considered this.  If both strings are nil, you length == 0, indicating that position 0, is the position which they differ.

Comment: You are correct that my method will return 0 if the string on which the method is called is nil.  It doesn't need both strings to be nil.  There isn't much you can do in this case as a message sent to nil is going to return nothing.  The issue with your version is that you will return -1 if the two strings have the same stem but one is longer than the other. I tried to help you fix your version and in my opinion you made it worse so I stepped in with my own answer. I am sorry if you feel I stole your answer.

Comment: +1 I wasn't looking at the problem that way.  Also, you have an extraneous ';' and you should not print out a long integer "%ld"

Comment: If the extraneous semicolon you are referring to is the one at the end of the method name then that is perfectly valid Objective-C. As to the %ld, I wrote and tested this category on the Mac, not iOS, where an NSInteger is 64 bit.  The %ld will work perfectly well on iOS where the NSInteger is only 32 bit.

Comment: Although, yes the semicolon will compile and work.  It serves no purpose, and this is absolutely no reason to do so.  The %ld will cause a compiler warning, so why not just %d?

Comment: I believe the semicolon is allowed so you can copy and paste the method declaration from the interface file into the implementation file without having to remove the semicolon.  Are you sure the %ld will give a compiler warning, I have just tried using %ld on both iOS and OS X to print an NSInteger and both compile without issue.

Comment: Also I have just given you some upvotes on a couple of your questions as a gesture of good faith.  Hopefully, there are no hard feelings.

Comment: Nope your answer was better.  I get that warning using the LLVM compiler 3.1 (maybe I have some flag set differently) Link about semi colon (Apple says leave off) -> http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-BAJHEIFE

Answer (score 3):

Start going through one string and compare each character with the character at the same index in the other string. The place where the comparison fails is the index of the changed character.

Comment: is idea, but I think that is a easily method, or not ?

Comment: The easy way would be to use a method form the NSString class to do  that, which internally would use this very same strategy. Unfortunately this method doesn't exist, so you'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: It is an easy method, the task is not very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-rangeOfString:`.  For example, `[string rangeOfString:@"l"].location`.  There are several variants of that method, too.